# How is Azure Bastion implemented?

Tags: firefox, remote-desktop, browser, azure

I'm sorry if this question is off topic but I recently used Azure Bastion which is basically RDP through a web browser to an Azure VM. The possibility of remote desktop in a web browser surprised me.

I am really curious in how it was implemented: server-browser wise. I wasn't able to figure out how it works -- in the browser's developer console (Firefox), there was no javascript involved, no websockets and there were no network connections opened. But the whole experience felt very smooth, like with a real RDP client. I'm also sure that I didn't install any browser addons, the whole thing runs in any browser.

Does anyone know how is it possible to implement RDP through a browser?

Comment: Pretty trivial with Canvas and Websockets. Check out [Guacamole](http://guacamole.apache.org/)! Unless you open developer tools early enough, you cannot see what happens.

Comment: Just a normal JavaScript canvas? I thought that the JS canvas is just a drawing API with basic shapes/colors in 2D/3D space and that it'd be very difficult to redraw a remote desktop scene in it. Apparently I'm mistaken. Thanks for pointing out Guacamole I'm gonna look at the source.